# Rake assets:precompile issue. Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.1. I'm trying to precompile assets.

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
  rake aborted!
  /home/user/project/public/assets/jquery-ui.min-0e8a11c7e970b57b4bf5c449cb14480d.js.gz has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/219

```
config.assets.precompile = %w( files )
```

instead of

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( files )
```

or

```
config.assets.precompile << %w( files )
```

Answer (score 9):

This is an issue with Sprockets.  You can fix this for now by removing the umlaut from "a" in the author's name in the comments.  Old:

```
Copyright (c) 2010 - 2011 Johan Säll Larsson
```

New:

```
Copyright (c) 2010 - 2011 Johan Sall Larsson
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I can't find this substring in any installed gems of my project.

Comment: In the offending file, search for the regex pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9 *\.()\/\-,:={};<>\[\]'+$_\?\^\!"%&#@\|] ` (that was for a vim search; you may have to escape some characters differently). You should be able to find characters like `±` and replace them with standard ASCII characters pretty quickly (that's what was giving me this error).

Comment: nice and thanks for the vim regex - had to add \t to allow tabs too

Answer (score 3):

This problem appears to be related to Heroku, Sprockets and interpreting non-ascii characters in your stylesheets.

On the first line of your top-level stylesheet, include:

@charset "UTF-8";

The charset directive must be at the top, or heroku's precompile will insert

@charset "US-ASCII";

Please note that if you're using manifests in your top-level stylesheet, you can't use the charset directive as well, since both of them want to be on the first line. My workaround is to include the stylesheets that have non-ascii characters separately in my layout (and not as part of the manifest).

I'd love a better answer than this workaround.

Comment: Jason, thanks for your answer. But I don't using heroku in this case. And adding charset directive dosn't help.