# Rake aborted! Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, utf-8

This problem has been plaguing me for hours! When trying to precompile my assets on the AWS instance, I get the following:

```
bitnami@ip-10-117-75-230:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/my_broker_app$ sudo bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb:82:in `block in entries'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb:82:in `reject'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb:82:in `entries'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:116:in `entries'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `block in each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `block in each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `block in each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `block in each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/bitnami/ru...]
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I am running `ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing the following:

```
$ cd opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike
$ sudo chmod 777 index.rb
$ sudo vim index.rb
```

Then, insert (press letter `i` on keyboard): `# encoding: utf-8` before first line.

Hit `esc` and then type `:wq` then press `enter` to save.

After, put permissions back for `index.rb` by doing the following

```
$ sudo chmod 644 index.rb
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I assume you've filed a bug report? :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else comes across this question, while Tomanow's answer didn't quite work for me, I discovered there were offending characters in my file, which is what caused this issue.

The files, which came from Open Layers version 2.13, contained a copyright symbol in the comments section of some of their javascript and css files. Anybody else having a similar issue could also attempt to look for and remove those characters, if that's a feasible. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653407/877472) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was happening on every rake task. I found out that it was due to the presence of some files with odd names that were accidentally created on the app's main directory, such as "?," and "\342,". Everything worked fine after I removed them.