# Adding JavaScript to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am a newbie to Ruby and working on my first project. Here are the versions I am using...

- ruby 2.1.1p76
- Rails 4.1.0

I am having trouble adding my JavaScript files. I am following [**this article**](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) (specially the **Site-wide Scripts** part) After reading the article, I saved the `jquery.js & jquery.validate.min.js` under **vendor/assets/javascripts** and my own script `accRefConfig.js` under **app/assets/javascripts/additionalJS** directory

So here is how my **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** manifest looks like (didn't delete the comments, hope that doesn't matter):

```
  // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files listed below.
  // 
  // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
  // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
  // 
  // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the compiled file.
  // 
  // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details about supported directives.
  // 
  // = require jquery
  // = require jquery.validate.min
  // = require_tree ./additionalJS
```

And my **application layout**...

```
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </head>
```

But this is giving me the following error....
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your time & help :)

BTW, I also tried `<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>`, but same error msg

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636934/rake-assetsprecompile-issue-invalid-utf-8-byte-sequence

Comment: @railsr, thank you for your response. I don't have access to my VM right now, will let you know when i get a chance to try this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that the error is throwing says *.../jquery.js has an invalid UTF-8 byte secuence.*

Try resaving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: thank you for your response. I don't have access to my VM right now, will let you know when i get a chance to try this out :)

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much, it worked!!! I guess you do learn new things everyday :) honestly never knew such a simple thing can matter.

in case anyone out there not so expart like me :P , this is what i did: http://redhotwords.com/unicode.html